# Why doesn't observing a photon collapse it's wave function into a B or W3 boson?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, superposition, wavefunction-collapse, electroweak

According to electroweak theory, the photon ($\gamma^0$) and weak bosons ($W^+, W^-, Z^0$) are all linear combinations or superpositions of the weak hypercharge boson ($B$) and the weak isospin bosons ($W_1, W_2, W_3$):

\begin{align}
W^+&=1/\sqrt2\ (W_1-iW_2\ )
\\
W^-&=1/\sqrt2\ (W_1+iW_2\ )
\\
Z^0&=W_3\cos\theta_W-B\sin\theta_W
\qquad\quad\theta_W\approx 28.13\deg
\\
\gamma^0&=W_3\sin\theta_W+B\cos\theta_W
\end{align}
Considering this, why won't wavefunction collapse occur upon observation of the photon? Is this because we must measure a property of the $B$ or $W_3$ bosons that is not shared among them and we do not have a way to do that yet?

To clarify, **official question**: upon observation of the photon, why doesn't the wavefunction collapse so we observe a $B$ or $W_3$ boson?

Comment: You observe a photon by having it absorbed by a detection apparatus. What does this have to do with its resolution to two unphysical states that are not even propagating mass eigenstates? Why ***should*** its wavefunction collapse into either of these states? Where did this misconception come from?

Comment: In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, measurement of an observable leaves  the system in an eigenstate of the observable ('collapses' the state to an eigenstate).  In your post, you stipulate that a photon *is observed* but you don't stipulate what the observable is.  Also, what *is* the observable that has the two eigenstates $B$ or $W_3$?

Comment: @HalHollis: The second and third sentences of your comment make sense to me, but I'm confused by this: *In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, measurement of an observable leaves the system in an eigenstate of the observable ('collapses' the state to an eigenstate).* It seems to me that this is true in *both* relativistic and non-relativistic QM (assuming the Copenhagen interpretation), and in any case this question is clearly about *relativistic* QM, since we're talking about photons.

Comment: Hi @BenCrowell, I confess the first sentence seems odd.  When I started writing the comment, I was heading in a different direction than what I ended up in and, after deleting some stuff in the edit box, I didn't adequately revise the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

We are presently living in the world where the symmetry you describe has been broken, i.e. the particles instead of being massless have acquired through the Higgs mechanism a mass, a huge one for the W and Z , and zero for the photon.

Energy conservation is an absolute law , and masses are part of the energy budget of a system under study. Thus  the photon and the Ws and Z cannot mix  the interactions, they are distinct particles described by different wavefunctions: the photon by a quantized Maxwell equation, the W and Z by Klein Gordon solutions.

Before symmetry breaking your question might have some sense, except as everything is massless I do not see how an experiment to detect them can be set up.